# typo3 extbase form with nested objects

Tags: forms, typo3, extbase

I'm using Typo3 7.6 and I have three Objects:

```
class Order extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity{
    /**
     * email
     * @var \string
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Ophi\OphiOrder\Domain\Model\OrderItem>
     */
    protected $orderItems = NULL;    
}


class OrderItem extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity{

    /**
     * @var \Ophi\OphiOrder\Domain\Model\Item
     */
    protected $$item;

    /**
     * @var \Ophi\OphiOrder\Domain\Model\Order
     */
    protected $theorder;

    /**
     * @var \integer
     */
    protected $amount;

}

class Item extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity{

    /**
     * title
     *
     * @var \string
     */
    protected $title;

}
```

An Order consists of multiple orderItems with an amount and an OrderItem has properties like title, etc. What I want to do now is create an order form that handles this nested object properly.

Now my controller has a formAction and a createAction. I assign all possible items as {items} to my formAction and my form looks like this:

```
<f:form action="create" object="{order}" objectName="order" id="orderform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <f:form.textfield required="1" property="email" type="text" name="email" />
    <f:for each="{items}" as="item">
        <f:form.textfield property="orderItems.{item.uid}.amount" type="number" name="orderItems[{item}][amount]" value=""/>
    </f:for>
</f:form>
```

When I debug $order in my createAction, the orderItems are there and amount is set, but for each orderItem the item attribute is empty. What am I missing, where am I doing this wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's to be expected since there is nothing which magically sets the backreference from `OrderItem` to `Order`. But you don't need this actually. The next time a persisted `Order` object is loaded all of its items will have that backreference loaded too. If you don't need this in your `create` action, don't worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo in your `OrderItem` class for the item attribute. Please try to remove remove the superfluous `$` in `protected $$item;`